# How to apply max_length to truncate the token sequence from the left in a HuggingFace tokenizer?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers

In the HuggingFace tokenizer, applying the `max_length` argument specifies the length of the tokenized text. I believe it truncates the sequence to `max_length-2` (if `truncation=True`) by cutting the excess tokens from the **right**. For the purposes of utterance classification, I need to cut the excess tokens from the **left**, i.e. the start of the sequence in order to preserve the last tokens. How can I do that?

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

train_texts = ['text 1', ...]
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('xlm-roberta-base')
encodings = tokenizer(train_texts, max_length=128, truncation=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tokenizers have a `truncation_side` parameter that should set exactly this.
See the [docs](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.truncation_side).

Comment: I've tested it. Works with the current transformers lib (4.21) and doesn't work in 4.16. Fortunately, it gives the same output as my code. There was a bug fix #15440 in between.

Comment: Is there a single example on the internet of where this arg actually goes? The docs are so dense there are 9000 different PrETrIaINeDOptioIMTokeENBErT-T2-GPT3 derived classes. I guess this goes into the `.from_pretrained()` method of the Tokenizer, but who knows??? It's not easy to test either.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer:

Mutating the `PreTrainedTokenizer.truncation_side` attribute worked for me.

```
s = " ".join(str(i) for i in range(600))

tokenizer.truncation_side = "left" 

t = tokenizer(s, truncation=True)
tokenizer.decode(t.input_ids)
> '[CLS] 284 285 286 ... 597 598 599 [SEP]'

tokenizer.truncation_side = "right" 

t = tokenizer(s, truncation=True)
tokenizer.decode(t.input_ids)
> '[CLS] 0 1 2 ... 443 444 445 [SEP]'
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76330762/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: worked for me but agree with @moken, would be great if you had any docs to add

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a solution, which is not very robust. Still looking for a better way. This is tested with the models mentioned in code.

```
from typing import Tuple
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

# also tested with: ufal/robeczech-base, Seznam/small-e-czech
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('xlm-roberta-base', use_fast=False)
texts = ["Do not meddle in the affairs of wizards for they are unpredictable.", "Did you meddle?"]
encoded_input = tokenizer(texts)


def cut_seq_left(seq: list, max_length: int, special_ids: dict) -> Tuple[int,int]:
    # cut from left if longer. Keep special tokens.
    normal_idx = 0
    while seq[normal_idx] in special_ids and normal_idx < len(seq)-1:
        normal_idx += 1
    if normal_idx >= len(seq)-1:
        normal_idx = 1
        #raise Exception('normal_idx longer for seq:' + str(seq))
    rest_idx = normal_idx + len(seq) - max_length
    seq[:] = seq[0:normal_idx] + seq[rest_idx:]
    return normal_idx, rest_idx


def pad_seq_right(seq: list, max_length: int, pad_id: int):
    # pad if shorter
    seq.extend(pad_id for _ in range(max_length - len(seq)))


def get_pad_token(tokenizerr) -> str:
    specials = [t.lower() for t in tokenizerr.all_special_tokens]
    pad_candidates = [t for t in specials if 'pad' in t]
    if len(pad_candidates) < 1:
        raise Exception('Cannot find PAD token in: ' + str(tokenizerr.all_special_tokens))
    return tokenizerr.all_special_tokens[specials.index(pad_candidates[0])]


def cut_pad_encodings_left(encodingz, tokenizerr, max_length: int):
    specials = dict(zip(tokenizerr.all_special_ids, tokenizerr.all_special_tokens))
    pad_code = get_pad_token(tokenizerr)
    padd_idx = tokenizerr.all_special_tokens.index(pad_code)
    for i, e in enumerate(encodingz.data['input_ids']):
        if len(e) < max_length:
            pad_seq_right(e, max_length, tokenizerr.all_special_ids[padd_idx])
            pad_seq_right(encodingz.data['attention_mask'][i], max_length, 0)
            if 'token_type_ids' in encodingz.data:
                pad_seq_right(encodingz.data['token_type_ids'][i], max_length, 0)
        elif len(e) > max_length:
            fro, to = cut_seq_left(e, max_length, specials)
            encodingz.data['attention_mask'][i] = encodingz.data['attention_mask'][i][:fro] \
                                                  + encodingz.data['attention_mask'][i][to:]
            if 'token_type_ids' in encodingz.data:
                encodingz.data['token_type_ids'][i] = encodingz.data['token_type_ids'][i][:fro] \
                                                      + encodingz.data['token_type_ids'][i][to:]


cut_pad_encodings_left(encoded_input, tokenizer, 10) # returns nothing: works in-place
```

Comment: Works, but with lib version 4.21+ use the accepted solution.